# Crystal Reports: using results of one report as input parameter in another

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a trying to combine two reports. One report Pulls a list of ID and the other report displays general data on those IDs.

I'm trying to write one report that uses the IDs generated in the first report as input parameters in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sub reports for that purpose.

select the ID in runtime and pass the value as a input to second report by this way you can get the required output.

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------

Create a parameter to get ID at run time.. and after that link that parameter to the sub report using sub report links which will pass the ID to record selection part of the sub report and when sub report is refreshed it will only get the data for that ID... make sure to prepare the sub report according to the required details